# Length plus minus other length?

Tags: calculations, lengths

Consider the following example:

```
\newlength{\textsize}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\textsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 1pt} % WORKS
\setlength{\parskip}{\textsize plus 1pt} % FAIL
```

How to make the failing line work?

Which means: how to set a length to another length plus and/or minus other values?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\newlength{\textsize}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\textsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 1pt} % WORKS
\setlength{\parskip}{1\textsize plus 1pt} % FAIL

\showthe\parskip
```

LaTeX lengths are skip registers so `\textsize` is a complete glue specification and can not take a further `plus` component. `1\textwidth` coerces this to a dimen, discarding any plus and minus components, so you can add a new plus component.

Answer (score 15):

Two alternatives to David's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247029/16967):

- e-TeX provides `\glueexpr`, which allows to add glue specifications:

  ```
  \newlength{\textsize}
  \makeatletter
  \setlength{\textsize}{\f@size pt}
  \makeatother

  \setlength{\parskip}{\glueexpr\textsize + 0pt plus 1pt\relax}
  ```
- If `\textsize` is not intended to have stretch or shrink components, then a dimen instead of a skip register can be used. LaTeX's `\newlength` assigns a skip register, `\newdimen` a dimen register:

  ```
  \newdimen{\textsize}
  \makeatletter
  \setlength{\textsize}{\f@size pt}
  \makeatother

  \setlength{\parskip}{\textsize plus 1pt}
  ```